# Generate all permutations of a card deck?

Tags: python, permutation

I have a card deck list of 52 elements in a specific order

```
[1,5,10,8,4...]
```

Each element of the list can be put in one of 5 available slots: slot 1,2,3,4 or 5.
How can I generate all the possible permutations of the 5 slots? For example one permutation is all 52 cards in slot 1, another one is first card in slot 1, second card in slot 2 and so on.
I've been thinking about using the permutation function of itertools but I can't figure out how to apply it the 5 slots concept.

Comment: So, you want to split the deck in at most five parts? Do you want to keep the order in each part? Between the parts? You have to be more specific. And first of all, what have you tried? Show us your attempt to solve the problem, your expected output, and what you obtained, then we can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, one assignment of your deck can be seen as a function which maps each element from the deck to the numbers `1,2,3,4,5`. Given the input is always the same, it can be represented as a list of `52` elements, where each element is a number between `1` and `5` which tells to which slot that element is assigned.

The [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function of itertools might help you. You might call it as:

```
for x in itertools.product((1,2,3,4,5), repeat=52):
    print(x)
```

However, the number of elements generated will be `5^52=O(10^36)`. This is a lot of elements, and it's likely you'll never finish printing them out in time. If you print a million a second, it'll take more than a billion billion years to get all of them.